# Netbeans with chrome integration is not working for HTML5

Tags: html, netbeans

I am developing HTML5 project in NetBeans 7.3 which will integrate with crome with an extension.But when i try to run the project,it is showing a blank page..please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Or this simple check could just work:Bypass you proxy server for local addresses

- Check your chrome proxy settings: settings>show advanced settings>Change proxy settings>LAN settings
- Check "Bypass proxy server for local addresses"

Re-run the project

Done.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the 100% working solution:

In the menu bar select the **Run** and in the list move the cursor to the **set project configuration**:

[image]

Which as you can see is disabled, so this answer does not work.

In the list change the **chrome with netbeans integration** to **chrome**. It will work definitely. Thanks!

Comment: It's not right answer, because anyone come to this question know about this.

Comment: Been driving myself mad trying to work out why some php projects will open in chrome but others wont. This solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by removing bad entries in my hosts file (%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts in Windows).
I only left one:
127.0.0.1 localhost
If you have problems saving the file, try switching off your antivirus' real time protection.
May be you should restart Netbeans|Chrome to changes take effect.

Comment: For some reason it started working again after I selected Firefox as a target and then switched back to Chrome. Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-gettingstarted.html has the setup instructions. Did you install the Chrome extension like it suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Check the hosts file. You should have this line there:
127.0.0.1 localhost

Maybe you have localhost pointed to other IP and the extension doesn't know the right IP address to bind.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the developer mode in Chrome to make the extension work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I did tried everything but none solve my problem so ended up using **Mozilla** for debugging, which is pretty straightforward and does not need any plugin to work. Simply change your browser preference from Chrome to Mozilla (in the top bar) and then Run your project.